# Vanishing of internal force of certain type

Tags: classical-mechanics, potential, potential-energy

Suppose I have an isolated system of $N$ mutually interacting particles, with two different interaction types $V_A$ and $V_B$, i.e., the force on the $i$th particle is given by $\mathbf{F}_{i}=-\nabla_{i}V_{A}-\nabla_{i}V_{B}$. Clearly, $\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathbf{F}_i=0$, because these are external forces of interaction. Question: What are the conditions under which the following statement holds?

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf{F}_i ^B = 0, \quad \text{where} \; \mathbf{F}_i^B\equiv -\nabla_iV_B
$$

To put it differently, can we claim that the total force resulting from a particular type of interaction cancels out? This appears to hold true for pairwise (two-body) interactions, as we can identify a force of equal magnitude but opposite direction for every force acting on a particle. However, I'm uncertain whether this principle extends to $n$-body interactions where $n$ is greater than 2.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by “interaction types”?

Comment: @BobD - Different interatomic potentials. For example, $V_A$ could correspond to a pairwise harmonic interaction and $V_B$ could be either a 2-body interaction of a different form (e.g. Lennard-Jones), or perhaps a 3-body interaction.

Comment: It has to be true if the two forces are actually different and independent of each other.